prove two generating sets are equal in a vector space
In the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space $\mathbb{Q}^3$ one considers the vectors:
$a=(-2,1,3),\, b=(3,-2,-1),\, c=(1,-1,2),\, d=(-5,3,4),\, e=(-9,5,10).$
Prove that $\langle a,b \rangle = \langle c,d,e \rangle.$
I'm trying to learn about generating sets but I fail to find some good examples. Can someone briefly explain the steps?

Well:
$a+b=c$,
$a-b=d$,
$3a-b=e$,
by inspection. So any element of $\langle c,d,e\rangle$ can be expressed as a linear combination of a and b . So clearly $\langle c,d,e\rangle$ is a subset of $\langle a,b\rangle.$
Also, $\frac{c+d}{2}=a$ and $\frac{c-d}{2}=b$.
So any element of <a,b> can be expressed as a linear combination of c and d. So $\langle a,b\rangle$ is a subset of $\langle c,d,e\rangle.$
So $\langle c,d,e\rangle=\langle a,b\rangle.$

Thanks! Somehow, i thought it's a different procedure.
